# simple_fields_for with a collection getting error User(#70104635753120) expected, got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I must be missing something obvious:

View

```
<%= simple_form_for(@book) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :user,:collection => @authors, :label_method => :email,:value_method => :id,:label => "Author" ,:include_blank => false %>
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

Strong params:

```
  params.require(:lesson).permit(:user)
```

Now when I post this I get the error User(#70104635753120) expected, got String

But when I change the f.input line to reference user_id instead of :user like so:

```
<%= f.input :user_id,:collection => @authors, :label_method => :email,:value_method => :id,:label => "Author" ,:include_blank => false %>
```

Then I get the error:

```
undefined method `user_id'
```

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Please post what `@authors` collection is, or how it's built.

Comment: Does your books table have a user_id column, or have you named it author_id in the database?